# Read from csv file of characters and storing in tensor

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["AlldTKmer4997.csv"])

reader = tf.TextLineReader()

key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

record_defaults = [tf.constant([], dtype=tf.string),     
               tf.constant([], dtype=tf.string),     
               tf.constant([], dtype=tf.string),    
               tf.constant([], dtype=tf.string),
               tf.constant([], dtype=tf.string),
               tf.constant([], dtype=tf.string),
               tf.constant([], dtype=tf.string),
               tf.constant([], dtype=tf.string),
               tf.constant([], dtype=tf.string),
               tf.constant([], dtype=tf.string),
               tf.constant([], dtype=tf.string),
               tf.constant([], dtype=tf.string),
               tf.constant([], dtype=tf.string),
               tf.constant([], dtype=tf.string),
               tf.constant([], dtype=tf.string),]


  col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15 
   = tf.decode_csv(value,record_defaults=record_defaults)

features = tf.stack([col1, col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15 ])

 with tf.Session() as sess:

 coord = tf.train.Coordinator()

 threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)


 for i in range(1000):

X = sess.run([features])

coord.request_stop()

coord.join(threads)
```

`
I am trying to read from a csv file of characters and special characters and have written the above code
The input csv file looks like this:

"A" "G" "T" "C"...(15 characters) "/" ")" "3" (15 special characters/integers)

But I am getting the following error:

InvalidArgumentError: Quote inside a string has to be escaped by another quote
     [[Node: DecodeCSV_2 = DecodeCSV[OUT_TYPE=[DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING, DT_STRING], field_delim=",", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](ReaderReadV2_2:1, Const_15, Const_16, Const_17, Const_18, Const_19, Const_20, Const_21, Const_22, Const_23, Const_24, Const_25, Const_26, Const_27, Const_28, Const_29)]]

Comment: Can you put this line `value = tf.Print(value, [key, value])` before `decode_csv` and provide the output when the error occurs?

Comment: Looks like the csv is space-separated not comma-separated file. You must provide another delimiter as the error output informs `field_delim=","`.

Comment: @frankyjuang there is still no output and the same error is popping up

Comment: @lepsch no it is a comma separated file only and the error is                                  InvalidArgumentError: Quote inside a string has to be escaped by another quote

Comment: Do you have a double-quote inside a field? For example, this is a normal field: "A". This is not: "B"B". If you are not sure about it, you can update some of your data in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow can only decode valid csv following [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180).

It seems that you might have a double-quote inside field where double-quotes are used to enclose. Refer to section 2.7 of RFC4180.

> If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
> appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
> another double quote.  For example:

> ```
> "aaa","b""bb","ccc"
> ```

Try add an extra double-quote before it.